# Cannot get gnome working on FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd, gnome

I am looking for help getting gnome running on a FreeBSD VM that I am standing up. Presently, when I log in, it takes me right to a console prompt for logging in instead of a GUI. If I log in as root and type "gdm" this is what I get:

```
** (gdm): WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager

** (gdm): WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out
```

I have added the following, as root, to the /etc/rc.conf file

```
    gnome_enable=”YES”

    hald_enable=”YES”

    gdm_enable=”YES”

    dbus_enable=”YES”
```

and I also added the line `proc /proc procfs rw 0 0` to /etc/fstab

What am I doing wrong? JUst as a side note, if I type startx I can get to a screen with xterm windows, and it seems like my mouse works there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the following from a console?

```
echo "/usr/local/bin/gnome-session" > ~/.xinitrc'
```

and then

```
startx
```

Comment: as the user you're currently logged in. Even if this is root.

Comment: how did you install Gnome? ports or pkg_add?

Comment: well I had originally done ports, because pkg_add was pointing to some bogus link online. I actually ended up using sysinstall with my disc. This got it installed finally, and I boot into gnome. As soon as I log in though, the keyboard stops working. Any ideas? I enabled hald already, mounted proc

Comment: I can post a new question if you want me to , since thats a slgihit different subject. I never did figure out why my ports install didn't work

Comment: What about `dbus`? It should be enabled too. So if I understood correctly now you can log in to Gnome buts it's just that the keyboard doesn't work whereas the mouse does(???).

Comment: dbus was also enabled, yes. And yes, the mouse works fine, it's just the keyboard that doesn't work once I get in. I read somewhere that maybe this means my keyboard is working in X, but just not gnome specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the package xorg and try again.

pkg install xorg

And please refer to the guide to config the Xorg accordingly.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x-config.html

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x11-wm.html